# How do I make the pyautogui.click() keep trying until the image show?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm fairly new to Python, or any code language actually. I'm trying to automate a task in my work, using the command pyautogui.click(), but due to the internal system, sometimes the image can take 3 seconds, other 20 seconds to appear. I would like to know if there is any way to make him wait until the image appears to continue running the code.

```
pyautogui.click('AutorizarOnline.png')
time.sleep(20)
pyautogui.click('Confirmar.png')
```

I'm using this right now, but it's not really efficient. I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a variable and try something like:

```
AutorizarOnline = pg.locateOnScreen('AutorizarOnline.png')
While AutorizarOnline  == None:
   time.sleep(1)
   AutorizarOnline = pg.locateOnScreen('AutorizarOnline.png')

pyautogui.click('AutorizarOnline.png')
```

This code assigns coordinates of AutorizarOnline.png to the AutorizarOnline variable, if no match is found it stays equal to None.